# Refer to another function inside module javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to refer to the getJSONS function from another function in the script, but I can't seem to do so.

The error that I'm receiving is `(node:5857) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: this.getJSONS is not a function`, how can I fix this?

```
module.exports = {
    getJSONS(bucket, storageDir, folderNameLength) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(`filesss`)
        })
    },

    setJSONSMetadata(bucket, storageOptions) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            this.getJSONS(bucket, storageOptions, storageOptions.prefix.length).then((jsonFiles) => {
                // do something
            });

            resolve(true)
        })
    },
}
```

Comment: How do you call `setJSONSMetadata` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution by Parker didn't work, I ended up copying the setJSONSMetadata function and duplicating it inside the getJSONS function. Weird, I know.

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `this` is pointing at the function in scope (in your case, the anonymous function passed to `new Promise`), and not pointing to your exported object.

One work around might be to store the value of `this` before the creation of the promise into a variable. Then call the variable instead of `this`. A common practice is to use the word `self`. It might look something like:

```
module.exports = {
    getJSONS(bucket, storageDir, folderNameLength) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(`filesss`)
        })
    },

    setJSONSMetadata(bucket, storageOptions) {
        const self = this; // store the value of `this` from the higher scope
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            // `this` inside here is different
            self.getJSONS(bucket, storageOptions, storageOptions.prefix.length).then((jsonFiles) => {
                // do something
            });

            resolve(true)
        })
    },
}
```